# Simulate correlated Brownian motions conditioned on future state(s)

Tags: stochastic-calculus, monte-carlo, brownian-motion, correlation, random-variables

Consider a model defined by 2 geometric Brownian motions

$$dY_{1}(t) = \sigma_{2} Y_{1}(t)dW_{1}(t)$$

$$dY_{2}(t) = \sigma_{2} Y_{2}(t)dW_{2}(t)$$

with $Y_{1}(0) = y_{1}$, $Y_{2}=y_{2}$ and $dW_{1}(t)dW_{2}(t)=\rho$. By performing a Monte Carlo simulation I want to compute

$$\mathbb{E}[\log(Y_{1}(T))|\log(Y_{2}(T))=a\cdot y_{2}]$$

for some future time $T\geq0$ with $t\in[0,T]$ and constant $a\in\mathbb{R}$. Additionally, I want to do a sensitivity analysis of the Monte Carlo results on the amount of paths and time steps. First, both geometric Brownian motions can be solved as following

$$Y_{1}(T) = y_{1}\exp(\frac{-\sigma_{1}^{2}}{2}T+\sigma_{1}W_{1}(T))$$

$$Y_{2}(T) = y_{2}\exp(\frac{-\sigma_{2}^{2}}{2}T+\sigma_{2}W_{2}(T))$$

Second, by solving $W_{2}(T)$ for $\log(Y_{2}(T))=a\cdot y_{2}$ I find

$$W_{2}(T)=\frac{1}{\sigma_{2}}(a\cdot y_{2}-\log(y_{2})-\frac{\sigma_{2}^{2}T}{2})$$

Third, the correlated Brownian motion up to time $T$, $W_{1}(T)$, can be computed as following

$$W_{1}(T)=\rho W_{2}(T)+\sqrt{1-\rho^{2}}Z(T)$$

with $Z(T)\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu=0,\sigma^{2}=T)$. Finally, to compute the expected value of $\log(Y_{1}(T))$, I draw $N$ times a random normal variables with mean $0$ and variance $T$ and compute $W_{1}(T)$ accordingly. By filling $W_{1}(T)$ in to the exact solution for $Y_{1}(T)$, I can compute $N$ times the value of $\log(Y_{1}(T))$ and take the mean to approximate the expectation.

My question is i) is this approach correct or should I look into simulating a Brownian bridge, since the problem is perhaps path dependent? And ii) If correct, is the approach of directly simulating $W_{1}(T)$ (always) more accurate compared to simulating a Brownian motion with multiple interim timesteps? Therefore, this problem should not necessarily need a time step sensitivity analysis as there is no dependance if the simulation is done optimally.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi there, IMHO, you do not need to delve too deeply into MC or stochastic calculus. Your log variables are bivariate normally distributed, the solutions can be looked up here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Bivariate_case_2. All transforms easily follow from that.

Comment: Also, there's on path dependence and no time step size dependence as your results are based on terminal observations, only. In a standard monte carlo scheme, finally, the estimator uncertainty scales with 1/sqrt(N).

Comment: Thank you, just out of curiosity: are there any methods/theories/technqiues to simulate Brownian motions with a fixed end point, like a Brownian bridge?

Comment: To my understanding, if the end point (as in : value X(T) at T) is fixed, then, yes, a Brownian Bridge is the way to go.